# Sympy: Simplifying square roots of squares

Tags: python, simplify, sympy

Sympy does not seem to be able to simplify an expression where the square root of a square of a variable is involved:

```
In [28]: a = x**2
In [29]: b = a**(1/2)
In [30]: b
Out[30]: 
    0.5
⎛ 2⎞   
⎝x ⎠   
In [31]: b.simplify()
Out[31]: 
    0.5
⎛ 2⎞   
⎝x ⎠
```

I do not get this to work with other variants of `simplify`, in particular I would have thought that `b.powsimp()` should work.

```
In [32]: b.powsimp()
Out[32]: 
    0.5
⎛ 2⎞   
⎝x ⎠
```

Does anyone know why this does not work, or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67982482/sympy-simplify-small-compound-fraction-with-squares-and-roots

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems with your example.

First `sqrt(x**2)==x` only for *positive* real numbers.

Second, for SymPy `1/2` and `0.5` are not the same things. The first is a `Rational` instance, the second is a `float` instance.

Finally, an example:

```
>>> x = Symbol('x', real=True)
>>> (x**2)**(1./2)
∣x∣**1.0
>>> (x**2)**(S(1)/2) # S() is short for sympify()
∣x∣
```

`sympify` transforms python objects to more adequate SymPy objects.

Comment: Thank you! Annoyingly simple and obvious, though. :)

Comment: Although: Is not `(-1)**2 = 1**2`, such that `sqrt(x**2)==x` is true for both positive AND negative real numbers? Further, for any positive real number `x`, `sqrt(x)` has both a positive and negative part?

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg, `(-1)**2 = 1**2` does not have much to do with the value of `sqrt(x**2)`. Moreover, while there are indeed two solutions to `x**2=a`, `sqrt(a)` has a single value (the positive solution). Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number

Comment: My point was only that if `x` is real, then `x**2` is necessarily positive. Anyway, again thanks for very helpful input!

Comment: Relevant Sympy issue: "'symbols' docs should be more specific", https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21629

Answer (score 3):

I assume you declare `x` as `x = Symbol('x')`. If you change it to `x = Symbol('x', real=True)` the expression should be simplified. You can find the reason why you have to explicitly state that your variable is `real` in the [sympy bugtracker](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=600).

Answer (score 3):

The function you want is `powdenest`.  If passed the `force=True` parameter, it will ignore assumptions

```
>>> powdenest(sqrt(x**2), force=True)
x
```

Comment: Thanks, `powdenest` seems useful.