# Sympy: Simplify small compound fraction with squares and roots

Tags: sympy, fractions, simplify

I have got the following situation (in Sympy 1.8):

```
from sympy import *
u = symbols('u') # not necessarily positive
term = sqrt(1/u**2)/sqrt(u**2)
```

The term renders as [image: 2D form]

How can I simplify this to `1/u**2`, i.e. [image: rendering] ?

I have tried many functions from https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html, and some arguments listed in https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html but could not get it to work.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796814/sympy-simplifying-square-roots-of-squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable needs to be declared as real number:

```
u=symbols('u', real=True)
```

Then the term is auto-simplified.

(I suggested a corresponding [Sympy documentation change](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21629).)

Comment: If you try e.g. `u=sqrt(-1)` you can see why it is necessary for `u` to be real.